# Changing content of php page

Tags: php, css

I wanted to know if there is something like a content place holder in php..like the one we use in asp..I have my index.php and I want only a part if the page to be updated, I am using css.I was thinking about making a copy of the index.php then rename it to, for example, register.php. then change the css tags where needed. Is it how it's done?
There are parts in the index.php that will remain fixed. For eg: list categories, sub categories. Now i want to implement a registration section. The list of categories should still be there and part of the index.php will change..

Comment: Could you clarify this a bit? Would you simply want to keep the framework of the page and insert different content each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET is object-oriented out of the box, whereas PHP is not. As such, there's no native "placeholder" to PHP. If you want this type of functionality, you ought to use a MVC framework like [Kohana](http://www.kohanaphp.com). That, or you could create your own simple template.

For instance, here is simple page:

```
<?php 
  include("header.php");
  include("navigation.php"); 
?>    

<h1>About Us</h1>
<p>This is our About Us page.</p>

<?php 
  include("footer.php"); 
?>
```

In this example, you'd have parts of your page that are relatively constant (header, navigation, footer, etc) all stored as pieces that are included within your primary files, such as index.php, aboutus.php, and gallery.php. In the above example, we see what a simple "about us" page could look like.

This model is relatively popular amongst young programmers, but if you're somewhat familiar with object-oriented frameworks, I'd encourage you to look at Kohana instead and work toward getting familiar with the Model-View-Controller method of development.

Comment: Ive tried it. It works as I want. I have include("products"); if (isset($_GET['ItemId'])) { include ("product_details.php"); } products.php displays the products and product_details display details of a specific product when i select one. But how do i clear the products.php, i mean on selecting a product i want to display only product_details.php

Comment: @chupinette: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. If you don't want the header, footer, etc., on `product_details.php`, don't include them :)

Comment: Ive got it! Ive used an if..else..:) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using php then just create a simple header ,footer and navigation section for all the page that you require and include that file where u require such like master page in asp.

Comment: Thanks for your help praveen.This is what I am actually trying to do